# In-App Subscription

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

when ever i test the subscription in application with testing account it return success callback and according to callback i store some information on my remote server......but when i publish it and test with other account the amount for the subscription deducted and it is performed successfully but i cannot receive success callback due to which im unable to access the content. how could we get transaction information from purchase model or inventory model other then that how could we get information about specific order ID like its remaining time etc, which is managed by google it self. how could we identify the user and (his/her) subscription on every device to access the content

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, "Key");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
            }
            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
        }
    });

    levelSubscriptionPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                          Purchase purchase) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "failed billing");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "purchase success Callback billing");
                Log.d(TAG, purchase.getToken());
                setSubscription(session.getUserDetail().getEmail());
            }

        }
    };


    mReceivedInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                             Inventory inventory) {

            if (!result.isFailure()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Query Inventory  failed Callback billing");

                /*Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "InventoryListener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Handle failure
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                        mConsumeFinishedListener);*/
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Query Inventory success Callback billing");
            }
        }
    };

    mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                      IabResult result) {

            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Consume finish success Callback billing");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Consume finish failed Callback billing");
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Purchase details in QueryInventoryFinishedListener like

```
Purchase monthlySubscription = inv.getPurchase(SKU_SUBSCRIPTION_MONTHLY);

        if (monthlySubscription != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User has already subscribed for monthly benefits.");
            Utils.Log(monthlySubscription.toString());

        } else {
            launchSubscriptions();
        }



private void launchSubscriptions() {
    try {
        iabHelper.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow((Activity) context, 
        SKU_SUBSCRIPTION_MONTHLY, REQUEST_CODE, new 
        IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, 
            Purchase monthlySubscription) throws 
            IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException {
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
                } else if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "---Success---");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "---Error---");
                }
            }
        }, String.valueOf(preferences.getUserId()));
    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You also add one extra parameter in "launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow" method. whenever you get Purchase details, you also get that extra parameter. so using this parameter you can identify user wise purchase
(in my case i add userId in launchSubscriptions() method)

Comment: Akshay did we need only one listener for subscription??

Comment: one last question did we call the last parameter developerPayload

Comment: i use QueryInventoryFinishedListener & launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow.
yes last parameter is developerPayload.